# Write in PROLOG are not printing the variable value

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print the elements of the list in the screen, but in a custom way. 
When I compile the code, appear this:
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Gvu.png)

My code:

```
printTray([L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10]) :- 
    nl,
    printLine(L0),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L1),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L2),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L3),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L4),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L5),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L6),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L7),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L8),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L9),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl,
    printLine(L10),
    print('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---'), nl.

printLine([P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10]) :-  
    write(P0),
    print('      '),  
    write(P1),  
    print(' | '),  
    write(P2),  
    print(' | '),  
    write(P3),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P4),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P5),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P6),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P7),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P8),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P9),
    print(' | '),  
    write(P10),  
    print(' '),  
    nl.
```

The list in the printTray clause are the lines of the tray. So, for each line I print the elements one by one.
I have no idea of the reason of this, I tried another ways but the result ever is the same.
The problem happens when I change the values of the list elements for a variable value.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `printTray`? Have you tried using the [guitracer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=guitracer/0) or any other means to identify why the variables are not bound?

Comment: Your variables are all unbound; how are you using these relations?

Comment: Have you heard of iteration? It will save you plenty of copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to replace all write/1 with an utility like

```
vwrite(V) :- var(V) -> write(' ') ; write(V).
```

Some refactoring of your code would lead to

```
printTray(Tray) :- 
    nl, maplist(printLine, Tray).

printLine([P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10]) :-  
    vwrite(P0),
    write('      '),
    maplist([P]>>(vwrite(P),write(' | ')), [P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9]),
    vwrite(P10),  
    writeln(' '),
    writeln('---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---').

vwrite(V) :- var(V) -> write(' ') ; write(V).
```

that paired with this test data

```
tray([
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [y,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,1,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,2,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,3],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
    [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]]).
```

yields

```
?- tray(T), printTray(T).

         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
y        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 3 
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
```